# how to modify values of dynamically created Widget from different class QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I know this question has been asked few times but all suggestions given there doesn't work for me.

*Overview:* I am implementing client server model and wants that as soon as msg arrived in server it should get displayed in main Qt widget. the widget , I choose to display msg is QLineEdit.

I have 3 files in project at the moment. Agent_A which is has all widget created dynamically. Then Server_test based on QTCPServer and sockClient for socket connection. I have received message on sockclient successfully from client but I don't know how to display it correctly on Agent_A .

I have added function in socketClient.cpp to update function in Agent_A but I guess when creating instance it always being NULL.

First a small snippet of my code and then what I have tried. may be you guys can input some valuable info.

Agent_A.h

```
class Agent_A : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Agent_A(QWidget *parent = 0);
     void setLineEdit( const& modifyStr ); // function to change lineEditCmdString
    ~Agent_A();

private:
    Ui::Agent_A *ui;
    QPushButton   *buttonStartServer;
    QPushButton   *buttonStopServer;
    // some other widgets 
    QLabel        *labelDisplay;
    QLineEdit     *lineEditCmdString;// I want to modify this value from sock client
    ServerTest   *server;

// few slots defined here
}
```

Agent_A.cpp

```
Agent_A::Agent_A( QWidget *parent ):
           QWidget( parent ),
           ui( new Ui::Agent_A )
{

  //define push buttons
  buttonStartServer = new QPushButton( tr( "&Start Server" ) );
  buttonStopServer  = new QPushButton( tr( "S&top" ));

  // some properties of other widgets defined here which is not relevant to mention here

  labelDisplay      = new QLabel( tr("DisplayMessgae" ) );
  lineEditCmdString    = new QLineEdit;// I want to modify this value on sock client
  labelDisplay->setBuddy( lineEditCmdString );

  // define signals and slots for Server
  connect( buttonStartServer, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( startServers() ) );
  connect( buttonStopServer,  SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( stopServer()  ) );


// some layout here  which agian is not important to mention here.
 ui->setupUi( this );
}

Agent_A::~Agent_A()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Agent_A::setLineEdit( const Qstring& modifyStr )
{
   lineEditCmdString->setText( modifyStr );
}
```

// now by socket client  which creates socket
sockClient.h

```
class SockClient : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
 explicit  SockClient( QObject *parent, QTcpSocket* socket= 0 );

 ~SockClient();

// I have added this function to update QLIneEdit in Agent_A
 void updateTextinParent(const QString &changeText);

signals:

private slots:
  void readClient();

private:
 // some other functions

  QTcpSocket *socketClient;
  quint16 nextBlockSize;

public slots:
};
```

sockclient.cpp

```
// constructor for sockclient and some other functions


SockClient::SockClient( QObject *parent, QTcpSocket* socket ) : QObject( parent )

{
   socketClient =  socket ;
  // create signals and slots
  connect( socketClient, SIGNAL( readyRead() ),    this, SLOT( readClient()  ) );
  connect( socketClient, SIGNAL( disconnected() ), this, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );

}

SockClient::~SockClient()
{
  socketClient->close();
  delete socketClient;
}

void SockClient::readClient()
{


  QDataStream clientReadStream( socketClient );
  clientReadStream.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_4_3 );

  QString strRecvFrm;
  quint8 requestType;
  clientReadStream >> nextBlockSize;
  clientReadStream >> requestType;
  if( requestType == 'S')
    {

      clientReadStream >> strRecvFrm;
    }

  qDebug() << " the string is " << strRecvFrm; // Has recieved correctly from client
  updateTextinParent( strRecvFrmMops ); // Now trying to update widget

  socketClient->close();
}



 void SockClient::updateTextinParent( const QString& changeText )
    {

 if( this->parent() == 0 )
{
  qDebug() << " Parent not assigned"; // This get printed ..
}
      Agent_A *agent = qobject_cast< Agent_A* >( this->parent() ); // ?? is this is right way to do..?
      if( agent != NULL )
        {
          qDebug() << " we are in updateTextin" << changeText; // it never get printed so I assume  instance is always nULL
           agent->setLineEdit( changeText );
        }

    }

// ServerTest.cpp where instance of sockClient is created

    ServerTest::ServerTest(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    {
      server = new QTcpServer( this ); 
    }

    void ServerTest::startServer()
    {
      connect( server, SIGNAL( newConnection() ), this, SLOT( incomingConnection() ) );
      if( !server->listen( QHostAddress::Any, 9999) )
      {
        qDebug() << " Server failed to get started";
      }
      else
      {
       qDebug() << " Server started";
      }
    }


    void ServerTest::stopServer()
    {
      server->close();
      qDebug() << "Server closed";
    }

    ServerTest::~ServerTest()
    {
      server->close();
      delete socketforClient;
      delete server;
    }

    void ServerTest::incomingConnection()
    {
      socketforClient = new SockClient(this->parent(), server->nextPendingConnection() );
    }
```

Comment: For `parent()` to be not `null` you should use [setParent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setParent) on `SockClient`, but `setParent` is for *Widgets* and `SockClient` isn't, why don't you just add a *slot* to the widget and *emit* a signal when there's new data?

Comment: I read in previous posts about emitting signal from different class but havnt understood it properly. Could you please describe how to do it may be with some dummy example.

Comment: `QObject` support [setParent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setParent) itself, so you can use it, but *slots* and *signals* are the best feature and the foundation of Qt, you should really learn about using them.

Comment: [Signals&Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) Add a *slot* on your *Agent* class, add a *signal* on your *SockClient*, *connect* them, then from *SockClient* just use *emit*.

Comment: Thanks to everyone . Everyone's input has not only helped me to solve my problem but I have also acquired new information.

Comment: Well, the issue  was , I tested (as suggested by @murad ) and found this->parent  is Null. Figure out and found error. In Agent_A i have created instance of SeverTest without "this". So replaced with something like  server = new ServerTest( this).  use advise of t3ft3l--i  about this-.parent and finally example by Alex. I created connection in servertest::incomingConnection  and slot in Agent_A and signal in sockClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple example:

qt.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .    
# Input
HEADERS += classes.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

classes.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Agent_A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
    void updateText(const QString &changeText) {
        qDebug() << "updateText: " << changeText;
    };
};

class SockClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
    void updateTextinParent(const QString &text);
 public:
    void incomingText(const QString &text) {
        emit updateTextinParent(text);
    };
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "classes.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Agent_A *agent = new Agent_A;
    SockClient client;

    QObject::connect(&client, SIGNAL(updateTextinParent(const QString &)),
                     agent, SLOT(updateText(const QString &)));

    client.incomingText(QString("hello"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed `Server_test` link element or it will be too easy to discuss.

Comment: just for curiousity.. Why do  i need Server_test link? I mean we emit signal from sockClient and it get in Slot in Agent so why we need server_test?

Comment: Secondly, cant we not have  connect in sockClient constructor?

Comment: This is the most simple example about how to connect two classes with slots and signals (It work I built and run it), I used the names of the question as classes to make @samprat easier to understand the example, but is just an example, he should learn himself about Qt slots & signals.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i the question of the OP is generic, I told him how to solve the first implementation with `setParent` and I also suggested him to use signals and slots instead, he asked for a dummy example using them and here it is, I really don't see reason to downvote, so much for helping.

Comment: @Alex class `Agent_A` has no idea about existing class `SockClient`, you can't see it? As i said if you create intermediate layer as `Server_test` you have no access to signals and slots of class another layer. See at author attached example one more time. Of cource, i'm sure you know how connect signals and slots of two classes as simple example, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i read the question title, I didn't asnwer to solve OP specific implementation. A signal and a slot are all that are necessary to answer the question, when he posted the question there wasn't signals or slots at all on his implementation, he updated the question after I suggested to use them

Comment: @Alex so do you think main problem he doesn't use slot/signal, but not pointer is invalid?

Comment: @t3ft3l--i I think *to modify values of dynamically created Widget from different class QT/C++* a signal and a slot are necessary. If the implementation doesn't work he should ask another question *why my implementation doesn't work?*

Comment: @Alex & t3ft3I, , Guys I know about signals and slots ,it just I dont know how to connect between signal and slots from different class. So Thanks Alex for teaching me that. Well I have tried your example . But I have used connection in sockCleint's constructor rather than in  main.  On using debug  I found that program correctly emit signal and I can see slot being called with update value. But widget doesnt change. for simplicity I have enabled = false or Qlabel and just making it true in our new slot function but it doesnt work.  Here is my example

Comment: SockClient::SockClient( QObject *parent, QTcpSocket* socket ) :    QObject( parent )

    {
        socketClient =  socket ;
        BridAgent *agent = new BridAgent;
       // create signals and slots
      connect( socketClient, SIGNAL( readyRead() ),    this, SLOT(   readClient()  ) );
       connect( socketClient, SIGNAL( disconnected() ), this, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );

       connect( this, SIGNAL( updateTextinParent(const QString& ) ),
                         this->parent(), SLOT(  updateText( const  QString& ) ) );
 
    }

Comment: @samprat sorry I'm not following all the code changes but, you say you see the signal emitted and the slot called, the incoming data is good? Within the slot the data reach the function that should update the widget?

Comment: I have added debug message in slot and I get expected string. But some how widget doesnt update. even If I do very simple thing will enable and disable widget  it doesnt work from slot. Do you think new instance of Agent_A get created and it doesnt reflect it old Widget?

Comment: @samprat, I think you should add few *qDebug* trace to verify if this is the case and eventually find the best place for the connection. One more thing, once you got it working, if `updateTextinParent` only need to call `setText`, try to *connect* directly to `setText` of the *widget*, it is a *public slot*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Agent_A *agent = qobject_cast< Agent_A* >( this->parent() ); // ?? is this is right way to do..?
    if( agent != NULL )
    {
      qDebug() << " we are in updateTextin" << changeText; // it never get printed so I assume  instance is always nULL
      agent->setLineEdit( chnageText );
    }
```

Could you please check first that parent is not NULL?
And could you please show code where you create instance of SockClient?

Comment: how to check if parent is not null?  after file server_test  creates instance of socketClient. I will edit my code to add it.

Comment: if (this->parent()) == 0) { qDebug ("Parent not assigned"; }

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can't modify text because of you set as parent to `socketClient` object `this` pointer in `Server_test` class, so parent to `socketClient` will be `Server_test` but no `Agent_A`.

So make parent `Agent_A` for `socketClient` object:

```
socketforClient = new SockClient(this->parent(), server->nextPendingConnection());
```

Or you can make some others workarounds.

One more **note**: you make connection to `newConnection()` signal at your `startServer` method, not constructor. So if i start server, then stop them and start again server will be connected twice to signal and slot `incomingConnection()` will be called twice too. So you need disconnect at from signal at `stopServer()` method or do connection at constructor of class or use [`Qt::UniqueConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: @samprat is it solution? helped to you?

Comment: Nope. It doesnt work. Also as uggested by murad , I have chekced if this->parent == NULL  in sockclient and it does. I have updated the code here